# XMLHttpRequest fails on IOS with blob and arraybuffer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to download an mp3 file, about 50kb using XMLHttpRequest (fetch isn't supported on IOS9), it always fails and I can't seem to get any useful error information:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", files_path + '/' + test['test'][i]['sound'].trim() + '?' + token);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if (this.status === 200)
            console.log('XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange: ' + this.responseText);
        else
            console.log('XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange Error: ' + this.status + ', ' + this.statusText);
    }
};
request.onerror = (function(group_test_index, test_index, game_index_, preload, i) {
    return function(e) {
        console.log(new Date().format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss") + ' - do_game2() XMLHttpRequest failed: ' + this.statusText);
    }
})(group_test_index, test_index, game_index_, preload, i);
request.onload = (function(group_test_index, test_index, game_index_, preload, i) {
    return function() {
        console.log(new Date().format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss") + ' - do_game2() XMLHttpRequest succeeded');

        // https://staxmanade.com/2015/11/how-to-base64-and-save-a-binary-audio-file-to-local-storage-and-play-it-back-in-the-browser/
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("loadend", (function (group_test_index, test_index, game_index_, preload, i) {
            return function () {
                console.log(new Date().format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss") + ' - do_game2() FileReader loadend');
            }
        })(group_test_index, test_index, game_index_, preload, i));

        reader.addEventListener("error", (function (group_test_index, test_index, game_index_, preload, i) {
            return function () {
                console.log(new Date().format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss") + ' - do_game2() FileReader error');
            }
        })(group_test_index, test_index, game_index_, preload, i));

        var b = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.response)], {type: "audio/mpeg"});

        reader.readAsDataURL(b);
    }
})(group_test_index, test_index, game_index_, preload, i);
request.send();
```

This prints out Error: 0, '' in Safari console... same problem in Chrome.

Is there a way to get more useful error information, or does anyone have any ideas why this doesn't work on IOS9? (Works fine on desktop)

Thanks!

Simon.

Comment: First of all, status code 0 is a wrong HTTP status, that code doesn't exist. The reason why webkit puts that is usually because the page has been refreshed, the ajax has been kept in memory but the window object has changed OR the request is cached. If the request is cached the browser will not send an actual request and will return the wrong HTTP code as 0. So, I suggest you add a complete random number instead of the 'token' just to make sure the browser doesn't cache it, alternatively send cache-control no cache from server. I stumbled upon it a few days ago as well.

Comment: Thanks or the info - I tried the rndom number thing but still facing the same problem...